# Hide switch in destination VC- Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uiswitch

I have 3 table view Controllers and a single destination View Controller.
I want to hide/ show a particular switch depending upon the segue of the parent table view Controller. I tried to do the following in each of the table View Controllers:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "editTableVC1") {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!
        let navController: UINavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let entryVC: NewEntryViewController = navController.topViewController as! NewEntryViewController

        entryVC.syncSwitch.hidden = true

    }
}
```

And if segue is initiated from 2nd Table VC, then set hidden property equal to false and so on.

Is it possible to do this? If so, How?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that syncSwitch is a IBOutlet. If this is the case then it might not have been instantiated when you create the view.

To overcome this create a property on your view controller to hold the boolean value and then use that to set your syncSwitch IBOutlet.

So in NewEntryViewController create a property called:

```
isSyncSwitchHidden
```

and use that to hold the value:

code in your prepare for segue method will use the new property instead:

`entryVC.isSyncSwitchHidden = YES`

Then in NewEntryViewController in viewWillAppear do:

```
self.syncSwitch.hidden = isSyncSwitchHidden
```

**Edit:**

Example code that I have written and compiled:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let desitinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! NewViewController
    desitinationViewController.isSyncSwitchHidden = true
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

class NewViewController: BaseClassViewController {

    var isSyncSwitchHidden: Bool?

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        print(isSyncSwitchHidden)
    }
}
```

---

Result:

```
Optional(true)
```

Comment: We,, yeah Switch is an outlet. I forgot to mention that if there is a simple property(ex. var a = "") and I want to change it in prepareForSegue(). How can it be done?

Comment: In the second paragraph it says to create a property to hold the value. I have added some more code to show this.

Comment: Do you mean when you are using a separate property? When you say it's not working, what is the actual result?

Comment: Yes, when I use a new bool property. It is not hiding the switch.

Comment: If you put a break point after: self.syncSwitch.hidden = isSyncSwitchHidden and print out both values, what are they showing?

Comment: Its in Swift. So, I have to use if let binding. So before binding, it shows nil, after, it just doesnt show anything. Not even nil.

Comment: And now when I initialized this new Bool property, I am getting "false" value.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. Was writing some code out and trying to get it working. I have posted a simple example above to show that this approach will work (see edit in answer). If yours still isn't working you might need to provide more code.

Comment: You might want to look at the code in between if (segue.identifier == "editTableVC1") { }. Maybe something is going wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you should not try to manipulate another view controllers views. That violates the principle of encapsulation, an important principle of OOD (Object Oriented Design).

In this specific case, what you tried simply will not work. At the time that prepareForSegue fires, the destination view controllers views have not been loaded so it's outlets will be nil.

@pls has the right idea.

Create a public property `hideSwitch` in your destination view controller. Set `hideSwitch` to true in your prepareForSegue. Then in your `NewEntryViewController`'s viewWillAppear, check the value of `hideSwitch`. If it's true, hide your switch.

That approach absolutely, positively works. I've used it dozens of times. If your attempt at that approach is not working then you have a problem with your code. Edit your question, add a

**`##New code:`**

tag at the end, and show your new prepareForSegue, plus the definition of the property and your updated `viewWillAppear` code in your `NewEntryViewController`.